# Deadbeef audio player does not retrieve online (freedb, CDDB) info about CD tracks

Tags: audio, music-player, audio-cd, file-metadata, deadbeef

Many Linux players (like Audacious, Banshee, Amarok, Exaile) can easily access audio CDs tracks info (names and other metadata) but Deadbeef cannot, although it has a cdda plugin that should do just that.

[image]

[image]

Along VLC, Amarok, Rhythmbox, Xine and Kaffeine, Deadbeef is one of the players that can read CD-Text (tracks info accessible offline, from the cd itself), but it oddly fails at accessing online CDDB, a somewhat trivial task these days.

Can those settings be adjusted to make this work?

---

Comment: Please try running it in terminal. Can you see any relevant output while attempting to connect to freedb?

Comment: [Does port `8880` work](http://www.freedb.org/en/faq.3.html#17)?

Comment: I'm not using Audio CDs, so there's nothing I could test against. I'm only trying to suggest things that seem reasonable at the moment. Could you run: `strace -f -e trace=network -o deadbeef-trace.log deadbeef` and then post output of `grep deadbeef-trace.log freedb`? We could see what happens to connect/sendto calls.

Comment: `grep freedb deadbeef-trace.log` - sorry, I often get the order wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34256/discussion-between-tnw-and-cipricus).

Comment: http://pasted.co/659a2df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the option **"Prefer CD-Text over CDDB"** (under Preferences-Plugins-Audio CD player-Configure): that should **NOT** be checked.

[image]

When it was, instead of preferring **CD-Text when available**, it just showed CD-Text and never CDDB info. And as CD-Text is [usually absent](https://superuser.com/q/1025110/162573), it showed generic names of tracks ('Track 1, 2 etc) even if CDDB data was available and CD-Text was not. ([It surely looks like a bug](https://github.com/Alexey-Yakovenko/deadbeef/issues/1458).)