# How to open Audio CD in Qmmp player?

Tags: audio-cd, qmmp

This should be possible, given that the latest Qmmp player has a CD plugin with options regarding CD tracks info - both CD-Text and CDDB.

[image]

But I see no menu option like 'Open CD' etc.

Is it there?

When trying to use 'Open files' to select Audio CD in the File browser, there is a message 'You can only select local files'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?34504-Qmmp-good-player&p=252825&viewfull=1#post252825), a solution would be to use the 'File - Add URL' option, and there add `cdda:///`. But that is a bit cumbersome, so, to have that with a click or two:

### In KDE:

Tested in KDE4.

**System Settings - Device Actions - Add**, and add the command : `qmmp cdda:///`.

[image]

Now, upon inserting an audio CD, one of the Audio CD actions will be the one set above

[image]

Also, after adding an icon to the desktop or the panel: right click on it, then 'Properties' (for the desktop icon) or 'Icon settings' (on the panel) and under Application tab change command to `qmmp cdda:///`

[image]

---

### In Xfce:

Create a launcher on the desktop or the panel, and then in the launcher options, change the command to the one specified.

---

Similar option may be available in other desktops.

**A general, all-Linux solution** is to create a `.desktop` file (executing the above command) and run it to start playing the audio cd after it has been inserted.

Something like this (to be added to desktop, panel or menu):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Audio;Qt;
Exec=qmmp cdda:///
Icon=qmmp
Name=Play Audio CD in Qmmp
Type=Application
```

---

It is also important to note that to have all needed plugins available, be sure to install the latest version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:forkotov02/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qmmp qmmp-plugin-pack
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use add url dialog in xmmp, write cdda:///